# Excel Formula that autofill an array with a list, based on an array

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array, auto-form-fill, list

I'm trying to do a formula that within a range makes a list based on info on a specific array.
What I need is an array that aufills this list based on the following conditions:

```
1)It has to be the first time the value appears
2)The value can't be " "
3)The value can't be repeated in the autofilling list
```

An example where the column A contains the data and the column B contains the formula.

```
Column A: | Column B:
AB12        AB12
            JH43
JH43        GO98
GO98        DT73
            AW64
AB12           
DT73
AW64
```

Im guessing the third condition should be !=(values from $B$1:B1) on B1, but I don't know how to make it different from a group of values.
The second condition is !=" " and the first condition I have no idea how to do it.

Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: You can do this faster with less calculations using sort and remove duplicates.

Comment: The example is simplistic so anyone can understand it, the real use of doing this function is a bit different. The column A is in a diferent sheet that is updated everyday with new rows and where dates and order is very important. The column B would be used to keep a registry of some info extracted based on the list this formula would get me. I don't mind the calculation, just want to do it automatically to avoid human error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a formula we need a title row.  The formula needs to start in the second row.  So in B2 put:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$9,MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$2:$A$9<>"")*(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,$A$2:$A$9)=0),),0)),"")
```

This is an array formula.  The calculations are exponential and too many of them or too much data will slow the calculations and sometimes stop excel.  This usually is in the thousands but be aware.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the E column within the countif is selected randomly?

Comment: @VicenteGre Sorry that should have been B, I was in column E when I finally got it right and forgot to change it before pasting it in the answer.  See edit.